# Does the SFMC (ExactTarget) API have locale support for object metadata?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Does the SFMC (ExactTarget) SOAP or REST API's have any support for specifying an alternative locale/language other than the default english? I'm trying to retrieve object metadata for the Contact object and I assume that core fields will have localized labels available; for example, Email, Name, etc.

Oracle's Eloqua product has this ability, and I'm wondering if SFMC has a similar capability.

I've been able to set the Marketing Console UI to an alternative language, but it seems that while the navigation and text are localized, the core objects do not have localized display names. I came to this conclusion by setting my Marketing Console to Spanish, then navigation to the Contact Builder and inspecting the Email Demographics attribute group.

[image: Contact Builder in Spanish]

Does anyone know if there is a way to get localized object labels natively from the SFMC (ExactTarget) APIs?